# Passing istanbul flags to grunt-jasmine-node-coverage

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

I am working on a project that is using the multiline node package. This allows us to create multi-line strings inside of multi-line comment tags.

The problem I am encountering is related to the grunt-jasmine-node-coverage node package.

Normally running istanbul, you can pass in the flag `--preserve-comments` and it won't strip out comments while processing the coverage information, otherwise it will default to false.

So far I have not been able to find a workaround for passing in this flag in the grunt-jasmine-node-coverage configuration. Is what I am trying to accomplish currently possible?